# use Apple Remote to run arbitrary commands to use for alfred.app

Tags: macos, remote-control, alfred

I use Alfred.app to rate tracks in an music app "swinsian" (double cmd on keyboard gives 5star rating..globally..nice)

I would like to trigger that kind of command to alfred via apple remote gen.1 (infrared) on macbook pro 2012

Can that Apple remote trigger any app (including Alfred) running on macOS high sierra?

Comment: Also, Alfred has extensive documentation and a dedicated support forum at https://www.alfredapp.com/. What have you tried so far to solve it?

Comment: yes but they are telling me i should find out first if the apple remote can initiate arbitrary commands in order to use for alfred.app - so its not a alfred issue in the beginning they say...and send me to you guys ;))

Comment: This has enough detail for someone to take a stab. Please invite the Alfred forum people here if we are a better system to get answers :) dedicated Q&A sites have some advantages over a discussion forum.

Comment: big questions seems to be if there’s any tool which will allow to interact with an Apple Remote from the command-line